# Multiple Logout Urls for Azure Enterprise Application Single Sign On

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, saml, logout

I have an Azure Enterprise Application service and im using it for Single Sign On. I intend to use the same Enterprise Application for multiple instances of my application each having its own domain (URL).

In the Single Sign On section, it only allows us to enter one Logout URL. Is there a way to specify more than one? Can this Logout URL be sent as part of the Logout Request?

Any suggestions?

I tried sending it in the request as a URL parameter (&logoutUrl= and &destination=) but it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK that is not supported as it's not part of the [OIDC](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-frontchannel-1_0.html) specification. To achieve this with native functionality, you'd need one client per logout URI.

Some alternatives you could consider:

1. Do not care about IDP-managed logout. This means that if the user logs out from a single application & the IDP, they stay logged-in in other applications. This might be unacceptable due to security or UX reasons. Low enough session lifetimes in applications might mitigate it.
2. Implement your own endpoint that handles the log-outs and register that as the single logout URI. This might be a significant effort and also have some security implications.
3. Just create multiple Enterprise Applications and follow the standard :)